# Why do when I type "-" or " " twice in a input-formatted TextFormField, the whole text disappears?

Tags: flutter, dart

I think the main reason of this problem is RegExp in FilteringTextInputFormatter. But I don't know why and how to solve it...

```
TextFormField(
  maxLength: 12,
  buildCounter: (
    BuildContext context, {
    required int currentLength,
    required bool isFocused,
    required int? maxLength,
  }) {
    return null;
  },
  cursorColor: Colors.black,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Just Put numbers',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[0-9\s-]+$')),
  ],
)
```

I use this code because I need to fill the `TextFormField` with a number pattern like 'xxx-xxxx-xxxx', not just any text.

FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
RegExp(r'^[0-9\s-]+$')),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be caused by the [system shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers-iphone/tane7f9690fb/ios) on iOS.
By default

- a double space   will be replaced by a dot `.`
- a double hyphen `--` will be replaced by a single longer dash `–`

As a result, your regular expression will not match anymore.
And the [`FilteringTextInputFormatter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/FilteringTextInputFormatter-class.html) will replace everything with its `replacementString`, which is an empty string by default.